# How to close file_browse dialogue window using javascript

Tags: javascript

firstly i performed the script

```
document.getElementsByClassName('image upload')[0].firstElementChild.click();
```

to display an Open File Dialog. Is there a way to automatically close this dialog after selecting a file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you provide a larger code snippet of what you have tried.

Comment: The browser should take care of that since the dialog box will be the only thing the user can interact with while it is open. When they click any button in the dialog box (or click the [x] to close it), control returns to your script.

Comment: If you are talking about the file selection dialog you get when activating an `<input type="file">` – no, you have no access to that using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> How to close file_browse dialogue window using javascript

You can't.

File Browse dialogues are *blocking*. No JS in the main event loop will run while one is displayed.

> Is there a way to automatically close this dialog after selecting a file.

I'm not aware of *any* implementation that doesn't close after the user confirms the selection (e.g. by double-clicking on the file or selecting it and then clicking OK).

Having the dialog close after a basic selection would be unexpected behaviour leading to security problems (a single click providing access to a file without the confirm step could leak data to malicious sites) and a bad user experience (the user might want to just preview a file before deciding if they want to pick it or not).